# Angularjs - when dom manipulation is assigned to button click it works, in directive it is incomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, raphael

I have tried now several approaches.

### Approach 1

I have a method which loads the data from the server. This is in my controller:

```
$scope.loadResults = function() {
  var url = "MY URL";
  $http.get(url).success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
      var tempResults=[];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      tempResults.push({date: data[i].date, p: data[i].p, result: data[i].result});
      }
      $scope.results = tempResults;
      $scope.drawChart(); //THIS IS THE METHOD I WANT TO RUN (this is approach number #1)
    }

    );
};
```

And here is my draw chart method (in controller as well):

```
$scope.drawChart = function(){
    var r = Raphael("pie");
    var tempTypeDistribution = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      tempTypeDistribution.push($scope.typeCount(j));
    }
    $scope.typeDistribution=tempTypeDistribution;
    if($scope.typePie){
        $scope.typePie.clear();
    }
    $scope.typePie = r.piechart(120, 120, 90, $scope.typeDistribution,
    {
      legend: ["%% - A", "%% - B", "%% - C", "%% - D", "%% - E", "%% - F", "%% - G"],
      legendpos: "east"
    }
    );

  };
```

This does not work. Chart is drawn but with errors. Adding `$scope.$apply();` gives this error: `Error: $digest already in progress` and adding safeApply does not do anything.

### Approach 2

In my directives.js I have created this watcher of `results`:

```
App.directive('chart', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];

      scope.$watch('results', function(v){
        var r = Raphael("pie");
        var tempTypeDistribution = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
          tempTypeDistribution.push(scope.typeCount(j));
        }
        if(scope.typePie){
            scope.typePie.clear();
        }
        scope.typePie = r.piechart(120, 120, 90, tempTypeDistribution,
        {
          {
          legend: ["%% - A", "%% - B", "%% - C", "%% - D", "%% - E", "%% - F", "%% - G"],
          legendpos: "east"
          }
        });
        scope.$apply();
      });
}
};
});
```

Again, this does not work. Chart is drawn but with errors. Adding `scope.$apply();` gives this error: `Error: $digest already in progress` and adding safeApply does not do anything.

### Approach 3

I have created a button in my view:

```
 <div id="pie">
         <chart ng-model='data'> </chart>
 </div>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="drawChart()" tabindex="3">draw</button>
```

And when I click it chart is drawn perfectly and exactly as I want it to be drawn. But I want the chart to redraw automatically when 'results' is changed. So I should use a directive, but apparently it does not work. Anyone can help out?

Comment: In approach two -watcher- is $scope.results initially declared outside of the loadresults function? If not, maybe there is no initial state for the watcher to compare against.

Comment: Also, you said in the first approach the chart gets drawn, but with errors.  What are the errors? And it looks like the drawchart() contains no data from the $http method, so why does it error?

Comment: Errors are rendering errors of the legend. Data is passed. I checked with `alert` and every time data is passed, chart itself is drawn okay but legend is screwed up. When I assign it to click everything is fine.

Comment: So it isn't clear how $scope.results should affect the legend, but if it's somehow dependent on the new results, wrap that portion of your $http with `$scope.$apply($scope.results = tempResults);`.  Otherwise, the watcher should work if $scope.results is declared outside the $http request.

Comment: any attempt at calling apply is met with `$digest already in progress`

Comment: Your second approach is better than the first - modifying DOM in controllers isn't what angular is made for, so that will always be more complicated. In your directive, you don't need to call `$apply()`: if it's inside a `$watch()`, that is done automatically. You only need to do that when you do something in an *asynchronous callback* that angular has no control over, e.g. a jQuery `click` that you put there yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by how graphael acts when output div is hidden:

http://www.shanison.com/2010/07/18/raphael-pie-chart-legend-stacked-line-problem/